# Как сделать подобный интерактивный фон на сайте?

Tags: javascript

https://digital.scotch.io/ - вот собственно сайт.

Почти в самом низу есть секция с интерактивным фоном, который реагирует на положение вашего курсора.

Подскажите, кто знает, каким плагином это реализовать? И можно ли как-то извлечь подобный фон с самого сайта?

Аналогичный вопрос и по поводу верхней части сайта: там фон неинтерактивный, но хотелось бы знать, при помощи чего реализовать такую магию?

Comment: http://vincentgarreau.com/particles.js/

Comment: Для фона можно использовать paper.js или любую другую библиотеку для работы с canvas http://paperjs.org/examples/meta-balls/

Comment: Большое спасибо за ответы. Особое спасибо AGS17 =)

Answer (score 1):

Вопросы а-ля "как мне достать это" решаются простым ковырянием сайта:

1. Находим элемент:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Если это `canvas` - то явно надо ковырять js.

2. Смотрим сорцы, перебираем файлы:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

3. Смотрим содержимое на предмет какого копирайта. Иначе - гуглим.
   [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вуаля, все нашли: http://vincentgarreau.com/particles.js/

И на будущее, SO не приветсвует такие вопросы.

Comment: Правильная ссылка: https://github.com/VincentGarreau/particles.js/